# How to get to closed form notation for the following problem from a summation.

Tags: summation

What i am trying to find is how to prove that closed form version of
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor} {_{(n-1)}}C{_{(2k)}} = \frac{2^{n-1}}{2}$$
I understand that the summation of ${_n}C{_r}$ from 0 to n is $2^n$ but i'm not quite sure how to prove the above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, we can rewrite the finite sum as
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor} \binom{n}{2k}
= \sum_{k=0, k \text{ even}}^n \binom{n}{k}
= \sum_{k=0}^n \delta_k \binom{n}{k}
\quad\text{ where }\quad \delta_k = \begin{cases}1, & k \text{ even }\\0, & k \text{ odd}\end{cases}
$$
Notice $\delta_k$ has the representation $\frac12 \left( 1 + (-1)^k \right)$,
this leads to
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor} \binom{n}{2k}
= \frac12 \sum_{k=0}^n \left(1 + (-1)^k\right)\binom{n}{k}
= \frac12\left[ \color{red}{\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}} + \color{blue}{\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k\binom{n}{k}}\right]
\tag{*1}$$
Compare RHS with [binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem)
$$\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} a^k b^{n-k} = (a+b)^n\tag{*2}$$

In particular, when $b = 1$,

- The piece in red in $(*1)$ equals to LHS of $(*2)$ for $a = 1$.
- The piece in blue in $(*1)$ equals to LHS of $(*2)$ for $a = -1$.

Replace these two pieces by corresponding RHS of $(*2)$, we get 
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor} \binom{n}{2k} 
= \frac12 \left( \color{red}{(1+1)^n} + \color{blue}{(1-1)^n} \right) 
= 2^{n-1}
$$

Comment: Could you explain how you used the binomial theorem to jump from summation to closed form notation?

Comment: @bobby I expand the answer a little bit, is this clear enough now?

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

We know $(a+b)^m=\sum_{r=0}^m\binom mr a^r b^{m-r}$

$$(a+b)^m+(a-b)^m=?$$

Set $a=1, b=-1,m=n-1$

Comment: But that would just provide an answer of 1 correct? are you hinting at a proof by induction or something?

Comment: @bobby,  Find the edited version